# Mysql Casting Performance Benchmark question / Data Architecture

Tags: mysql, performance, architecture

Currently I'm working off of a data set which is just redicolus; a flat file from multiple vendors which has no rhyme or reason; and sits at about 200 columns.. There are 15 which are common between those 200, which I have pulled out into another table.

From the other 185 columns they are a mix of varchar's, int's datetime's and multiple string values.

Right now I'm trying to decide how best to store these other 185 columns; as in a flat table currently it's just proving to scale super poorly.  I have two solutions setup, however I do not know which one is better.

One is storing the meta data for each of the columns in separate tables (seen in image) [image: Image architecture]

However it seems that using this method; it's going to be very difficult if down the road I need to do queries on items which lie within here.

THe other method I've thought of is throwing all the columns into a table which has id, value, datatype, than when doing queries cast the value to the datatype ie:

```
 select * from foo where cast(col_to_query) as int < 5
```

however I'm not sure what the performance is like when doing things that way.

Question:

Which of these two methods would be better performance wise and which one would you recommend (or if there is a better option I would love to hear it).

Thank you

Comment: How many rows are we talking?

Comment: "however I'm not sure what the performance is like when doing things that way." --- not at all. Since you've applied a function to the field - you'll get fullscan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach will scale even worse than a single table, and will be incredibly difficult to query to boot.

I would suggest using a single table, with all the columns in it, as a starting approach.  You said it scales poorly though.  What do you mean by that?  How is it scaling poorly?  Are queries taking a long time to return?  Have you indexed the table properly for your queries? The number of columns doesn't often affect the time for queries to return significantly, other than if they're returning a huge amount of data.  If that's the case, how you store it under the covers will have little effect on the query response time if all the time is being spent in transferring data between mysql and the client.  Be sure that you're only selecting the columns you care about if this is the case.  Don't do "select *".

Another option would be to use a table inheritance strategy.  In this case, you would have one parent table that stores the 15 common attributes, and a "type" that would identify the type of records, based upon the file it came from, or you could call it the source.  Then, create an extension table with a 1 to 0-1 mapping for each of the different files with the custom columns only for each specific file.  This won't perform as well as one large table most likely, as you'll have to do joins, but it will help reduce the need for a whole bunch of columns on one table that are often null.

This would look something like this:

```
create table master (
  master_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  type int,
  <field1> int,
  <field2> varchar(20),
  ...
);

create table file1_data (
  master_id int not null primary key,
  type int,
  <field16> int,
  <field17> varchar(20),
  ...
);
```

Query it like this:

select , , ...
from master
inner join file1_data
on file1_data.master_id = master.master_id
where ...

Comment: 200 columns; with a ton of data in it.. most of the columns are either varchar(255) or text fields. The inserts are taking a long time to insert the data initially. Can you explain a little more about an extension table? I don't fully understand that.

Comment: You're probably not going to get around that.  Whether you're storing the data in one table or a bunch, if you have that many columns, the inserts are going to be somewhat slow.  Consider loading the data using a bulk insert approach such as LOAD DATA INFILE.  That might speed it up. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Comment: Does the file differ for each vendor?  Is the 185 columns the total number of columns across all vendors' own files, or do all vendors send the same file?

Comment: Basically, what do you mean by the 15 "common" fields versus the other 185.

Comment: Yea sadly the file is different per vendor... yea the 15 common fields are the ones which are common across all vendors.

Comment: Can you update your question with some example common fields and some of the ones that are unique per vendor?